# JQuery getting text of select results in a repeating value

Tags: jquery, select, text

I have a drop down list that displays as this:

```
 <li class="row" recordid="15">
 <!--...code...-->
 <p class="departments">
 <select name="department" id="department">
     <option value="null">Select A Department</option>
     <option value="1">Graphic Design</option>
     <option value="2">Photography</option>
     <option value="3">Advertising</option>
     <option value="4">Custom Promotions</option>
<select>
</p>
<!--more code-->
</li>
```

when I try to get the current selection of the select it is recording it twice (this is being initiated off a button click to confirm edits to the row):

```
 $(".confirmEdit").live('click', function() { 

//get row id
var dbid = $(this).parent().attr("recordid");

//user
    var thisuser = "AUser";

//get values
var department = $("#department").val();
var deptDisplay = $("#department option[value='" + department + "']").text();
console.log(deptDisplay);
    //...
 });
```

if Graphic Design is selected my results are Graphic DesignGraphic Design. Am I pulling the data wrong? Could this be a bug? I'm dynamically building the drop downs (using some PHP/AJAX/JS mojo) but the indexes and text appear fine.

Comment: Your id is plural `departments`, but you referance it singularly `department`

Comment: Thanks, that's just a typo from me (since the select is being dynamically built I just wrote the html on this page) - it should be singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're getting it twice, but to get the `text` of the selected `<option>`, just use the [`selected-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) like this:

```
var deptDisplay = $("#departments option:selected").text();
```

or this without jQuery:

```
var depts = document.getElementById('departments');
var deptDisplay = depts.options[ depts.selectedIndex ].text;
```

Comment: @Pruitlgoe: Please remember to click the large checkmark to the left of this answer if it was helpful. Thanks. :o)

Comment: I couldn't because there's a time delay on accepting the answer and I was leaving work. Took care of it first thing this morning.